# CSS changing style

Tags: css, ionic2

I am using Ionic2, and have and `ion-content` tag. Depending on a variable, I want to change the style on the tag.

I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
<ion-content *ngIf="persoModel.type === 0" padding class="person-content-wanted">
<ion-content *ngIf="personModel.type === 1" padding class="person-content-offered">
...
</ion-content>
```

Can anyone please suggest a way yo achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here `personModel` is a boolean if it is true you will get `person-content-wanted` class if it is false you will get `person-content-offerred`

```
 <ion-content [class]="personModel? 'person-content-wanted' : 'person-content-offered'">
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it puts the class into `ng-reflect-ngclass`, which doesn't seem to work. `<ion-content id="person-content" class="has-infinite-scroll" padding="" ng-reflect-ngclass="person-content-wanted">`

Comment: If I change `[ngclass]` to `[class]`, it works. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another way to do it, according to [Ng2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html), the proper way to use `ngClass` is

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
```

So in your case it should work by doing:

```
<ion-content padding [ngClass]="{'person-content-wanted': persoModel.type === 0, 'person-content-offered': personModel.type === 1}"]>
...
</ion-content>
```